# Running kubernetes on OSX via Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to get `Kubernetes` running on `OSX`.

I've downloaded and installed Docker Toolbox and have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md).

When I try to run `kubectl get nodes` I get the following error:

```
error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
```

I noticed that the guide has a note for `OSX` but it is for `boot2docker` which has been deprecated in favor of Docker Toolbox.

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in a pull request on [github](https://github.com/gabrfarina/kubernetes/commit/416225f5541578106600ba6c18ffe2294a2a6aa8).

This is for `docker-machine` version .4

```
docker-machine env default
ssh -f -T -N -L8080:localhost:8080 -l docker $(echo $DOCKER_HOST | cut -d ':' -f 2 | tr -d '/')
```

Type `tcuser` as the password.

You should now be able to successfully run `kubectl get nodes`